# Base url caught undefined PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i was do some project, i move some php file into application/views
when i try to call
"localhost/siak/application/views/tabel-lookup.php" it went blank white page

after i check the view page source there's error "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function base_url" on "" rel="stylesheet" />"

i was already set the config and everything in the back so i dont know what's the problem[here's the warning said](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCXnu.png)

Comment: why are you trying to call view file thru URL? "localhost/siak/application/views/tabel-lookup.php" does not seems to be a valid CI URL

Comment: i set that on side-menu, the menu "tabel-lookup" i set with that url so it'll open on views file

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CodeIgniter 3, you'll have to include the helper for this function to work. Here's how to enable it for the whole site:

In the file `application/config/autoload.php`, add 'url' to the list of helpers:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

To enable it on a page by page basis, put this in the `constructor` function of your `controller` - or at the very least, at the top of the page you're using.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Also (sorry if you already know this), with CodeIgniter, you know you should access views through the controller, not directly. For example, in a codeigniter app, `www.example.com/admin/users.php` would route to a controller file called 'admin' and in that controller there would be a function called 'users' which would load a view like this `$this->load->view('some_directory/users', $data);`

Comment: in my controller, i set  $this->load->view("Dashboard");
does it mean the CI program would only read the Dashboard file url?

Comment: No, it means that it will load a view  in your views folder called 'Dashboard.php'.

Comment: anyway, i also already set the helper in controller file.. but it keep giving me fatal error

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter are you using? What is the fatal error?

Comment: CI 3,
the error was " fatal error, uncaught error call to undefined function base_url() "

Comment: @FajarFalahSyafendra - I just updated my answer with `autoload` options

Comment: @FajarFalahSyafendra - any luck with autoload?

Comment: [UPDATE] i already set everything but the file that i want to call still error blank page and the error in view page source said it was undefined base_url

i try to use site_url and other else but didnt word
my base url at config.php was this :
(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].
      str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",
      $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);